# Position values magically flipping signs

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I'm trying to make a 2D sliding puzzle game (like 15 puzzle). My main problem is getting the squares to stop just before they touch. I don't want to use colliders because I'm scared they might pop out of place, so I've written a script that I'll place on each of the squares. The script uses an overlapcircle to detect other colliders and then determine where they are in relation to the square you're dragging (above, below, left, right) by comparing the differences in x value and y value (x difference > y difference = on the left or right). If there is another square on your side, it should stop the square. And it does pretty much, but once you get the point where the square should be stopped, it flips the difference's value (negative to positive or vice versa) and the square thinks it's on the left and right side of the other square simultaneously. What the heck? Here's the square's code in full. Hopefully I explained this clearly haha.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Square : MonoBehaviour {

// Click and drag
Vector3 mouse;
Vector3 square;
Vector3 offset;
Vector3 newMouse;
Vector3 newPosition;

// Bounds
float xBoundMin;
float xBoundMax;
float yBoundMin;
float yBoundMax;

// Detecting tiles
Vector2 origin;
Collider2D[] tilesTouched;
Vector3 tilePosition;

public float radius;
int i;
int numberOfTiles;
float xDifference;
float yDifference;
float cushion;
bool isOnRight;
bool isOnLeft;
bool isOnTop;
bool isOnBottom;

// General
Transform thisTransform;
Collider2D thisCollider;

void Start () {
    // Bounds
    xBoundMin = -1.67f;
    xBoundMax = 1.67f;
    yBoundMin = -1.67f;
    yBoundMax = 1.67f;

    // Detecting tiles
    radius = .91f;
    cushion = 1.66f;

    // General
    thisTransform = GetComponent<Transform> ();
    thisCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D> ();
}

void OnMouseDown () {
    GetOffset ();
}

void OnMouseDrag () {
    DragObject ();
}

void Update () {
    DetectTiles ();
}

void GetOffset () {
    // Calculate offset with the transform's position and mouse position, while preserving the z position of the transform
    square = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (thisTransform.position); // Get transform's screen point to use in $mouse's vector as $mouse.z
    mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, square.z));
    offset = thisTransform.position - mouse;
}

void DragObject () {
    // Drag object within bounds
    newMouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, square.z));
    newPosition = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp (newMouse.x + offset.x, xBoundMin, xBoundMax), Mathf.Clamp (newMouse.y + offset.y, yBoundMin, yBoundMax), newMouse.z + offset.z); // Mathf.Clamp (float, min, max) to keep in bounds
    thisTransform.position = newPosition;
}

void DetectTiles () {
    // Check if any other tiles are next to it and where
    origin = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    tilesTouched = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll (origin, radius);
    numberOfTiles = tilesTouched.Length;

    isOnRight = false;
    isOnLeft = false;
    isOnTop = false;
    isOnBottom = false;

    xBoundMax = 1.67f;
    xBoundMin = -1.67f;
    yBoundMax = 1.67f;
    yBoundMin = -1.67f;

    for (i = 1; i < numberOfTiles; i++) {
        tilePosition = tilesTouched[i].transform.position;
        xDifference = tilePosition.x - origin.x;
        yDifference = origin.y - tilePosition.y;

        if (Mathf.Abs (xDifference) > Mathf.Abs (yDifference)) {
            if (xDifference > 0) {
                isOnLeft = true;
                xBoundMax = tilePosition.x - cushion;
            } else if (xDifference < 0) {
                isOnRight = true;
                xBoundMin = origin.x - cushion;
            }
        } else if (Mathf.Abs (xDifference) < Mathf.Abs (yDifference)) {
            if (yDifference < 0) {
                isOnTop = true;
                // yBoundMax = origin.y;
            } else if (yDifference > 0) {
                isOnBottom = true;
                // yBoundMin = origin.y;
            }
        }
    }

    Debug.Log (isOnRight + ", " + isOnLeft + ", " + isOnTop + ", " + isOnBottom + ", " + xDifference + ", " + tilePosition.x + ", " + origin.x);
}

}
```

Comment: You should consider snapping the block into position, instead of trying to determine when to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How would I go about doing that?